# Why Python subprocesses won't properly capture signals?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, signals, posix

Let's have a tiny little program that is supposed to capture (and ignore) SIGTERM signal:

```py
# nosigterm.py:

import signal
import time

def ignore(signum, frame):
    print("Ignoring signal {}".format(signum))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ignore)
  signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, ignore)

  while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    print("... in loop ...")
```

When executed from another python script as a subprocess, sending SIGTERM terminates this subprocess, which I find strange:

```py
# parent_script.py:

import signal
import subprocess
import sys

args = [sys.executable, "nosigterm.py"]
prog = subprocess.Popen(args)
assert prog.poll() is None

prog.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
print("prog.poll(): {}".format(prog.poll()))
assert prog.poll() is None, "Program unexpectedly terminated after SIGTERM"
```

The output is:

```
$ python3 parent_script.py 
prog.poll(): None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parent_script.py", line 13, in <module>
    assert prog.poll() is None, "Program unexpectedly terminated after SIGTERM"
AssertionError: Program unexpectedly terminated after SIGTERM
```

Would you have any idea why it is so?

Note that if `nosigterm.py` is executed as a standalone python script (`python3 nosigterm.py`) and SIGTERM sent by the system `kill` command (in another terminal), it behaves as it should:

```
$ python3 nosigterm.py 
... in loop ...
... in loop ...
Ignoring signal 15
... in loop ...
... in loop ...
... in loop ...
```

I have tried three python versions (2.7, 3.6 and 3.7) and two Linux operating systems (CentOS 7 and Debian 9), all with the same results. If I replace `nosigterm.py` by a binary application written in C that captures SIGTERM (via `sigaction()`), the behavior is still unchanged, so it must be somehow related to the parent python process.

Also note that Popen parameters `restore_signals=True/False` or `preexec_fn=os.setsid/os.setpgrp` did not make any change, either.

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me understand this. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce in Python 3.8.2 on macOS, but not in Python 3.9 on the same machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a race condition.

You are forking and immediately sending the signal, so it's a race for the child process to ignore it before it gets killed.

Furthermore, your parent script has a race condition in checking whether the script has died. You signal the script and immediately check if it's dead, so it's a race for the child to die before the check happens.

If you add a `time.sleep(1)` before sending the signal, you'll make sure the child wins the race and therefore you get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I confirm that adding `time.sleep(n)` at the suggested places resolves the situation.